# gridview control not refreshing?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have what I hope is a simple question. I have a gridview control that's bound to a sqldatasource.

First, the relevant code:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="cboCustomerID" runat="server"
    DataSourceID="DataSourceCustomer" DataTextField="CustomerName" DataValueField="CustomerID">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList ID="cboStaffID" runat="server"
    DataSourceID="DataSourceStaff" DataTextField="StaffFullName" DataValueField="StaffID">
</asp:DropDownList>
<div><gcctl:MyCheckBox ID="chkShowClosed" Text="Show Closed Jobs?" Checked="false" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" /></div>
<div><asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" Text="Search" /></div>

<div id="customersearchresults" class="searchresults">
    <asp:SqlDataSource id="gvJobsDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:GeekCommandConnString %>"
        SelectCommand="SELECT j.JobID, j.JobName, s.JobStatus, jal.[JobAssignmentsFullList]
            FROM (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Jobs] WHERE ((NULLIF(@CustomerSearch,'') IS NOT NULL AND CustomerID = @CustomerSearch) OR (NULLIF(@CustomerSearch,'') IS NULL))) j
            INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM [list].[JobStatuses] WHERE ((@ShowClosed = 0 AND IsStatusOpen = 1) OR (@ShowClosed = 1)) AND IsActive = 1) s ON j.JobStatusID = s.JobStatusID
            LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[JobAssignments] WHERE ((NULLIF(@StaffSearch,'') IS NOT NULL AND StaffID = @StaffSearch) OR (NULLIF(@StaffSearch,'') IS NULL))) ja ON j.JobID = ja.JobID
            LEFT JOIN [dbo].[udv_JobAssignmentsCommaDelimited] jal ON j.JobID = jal.JobID
            ">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="CustomerSearch" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="StaffSearch" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ShowClosed" Type="Boolean" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>

    <asp:GridView ID="gvJobs" runat="server" AllowSorting="True"  
        AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        DataKeyNames="JobID"
        DataSourceID="gvJobsDataSource"
        AutoGenerateDeleteButton="False"    
        AutoGenerateEditButton="False" 
        AutoGenerateSelectButton="False"
        CssClass="searchresultsgrid" 
        AllowPaging="True" PageSize="50"
        OnRowCommand="gvJobs_RowCommand"
        EmptyDataText="No matching jobs on record." >
        <Columns>
            <asp:templatefield>
                <itemtemplate>
                    <asp:linkbutton id="btnEdit" runat="server" CommandName="JobEdit" OnClientClick="PageForm.target ='_blank';" text="View/Edit" />
                </itemtemplate>
            </asp:templatefield>

            <asp:BoundField DataField="JobID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="false" ReadOnly="true" Visible="false" SortExpression="JobID" />
            <asp:templateField HeaderText="Job Name" SortExpression="JobName">
                <ItemTemplate><%# Eval("JobName") %></ItemTemplate>
            </asp:templateField>
            <asp:templateField HeaderText="Assigned to" SortExpression="JobAssignmentsFullList">
                <ItemTemplate><%# Eval("JobAssignmentsFullList") %></ItemTemplate>
            </asp:templateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</div>


<asp:SqlDataSource ID="DataSourceCustomer" runat="server"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:GeekCommandConnString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT NULL AS [CustomerID]
                , NULL AS [CustomerName]
            UNION SELECT [CustomerID]
                ,[CustomerName]
            FROM [GeekCommand].[dbo].[Customers]
            WHERE ((@ShowInactive = 0 AND IsActive = 1) OR (@ShowInactive = 1))
            ORDER BY CustomerName">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="ShowInactive" Type="Boolean" ControlID="chkCustomersShowInactive" PropertyName="Checked" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="DataSourceStaff" runat="server"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:GeekCommandConnString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT NULL AS [StaffID]
                , NULL AS [StaffFullName]
            UNION SELECT [StaffID]
                ,COALESCE([FirstName], [Nickname], '') + ' ' + COALESCE([LastName], '') AS StaffFullName
            FROM [GeekCommand].[dbo].[Staff]
            WHERE ((@ShowInactive = 0 AND IsActive = 1) OR (@ShowInactive = 1))
            ORDER BY StaffFullName">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="ShowInactive" Type="Boolean" ControlID="chkStaffShowInactive" PropertyName="Checked" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

And the relevant aspx.cs code:

```
int? iCustomerID;
int? iStaffID;

//--------
protected void SetIDs()
{
    this.iCustomerID = null;
    this.iStaffID = null;

    if (Request.QueryString["customerid"] != null) //new customer
    {
        try
        {
            this.iCustomerID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["customerid"]);
        }
        catch { }
    }

    if (Request.QueryString["staffid"] != null) //new customer
    {
        try
        {
            this.iStaffID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["staffid"]);
        }
        catch { }
    }

    if (iCustomerID != null)
    {
        cboCustomerID.SelectedValue = iCustomerID.ToString();
    }

    if (iStaffID != null)
    {
        cboStaffID.SelectedValue = iStaffID.ToString();
    }
}

//--------
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        SetIDs();
    }
}

//--------
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    gvJobsDataSource.SelectParameters["CustomerSearch"].DefaultValue = cboCustomerID.SelectedValue.ToString();
    gvJobsDataSource.SelectParameters["StaffSearch"].DefaultValue = cboStaffID.SelectedValue.ToString();
    gvJobsDataSource.SelectParameters["ShowClosed"].DefaultValue = chkShowClosed.Checked.ToString();

    gvJobs.DataBind();
}
```

When I run the following in SSMS, I get 2 rows back, as I should:

```
DECLARE @CustomerSearch int, @StaffSearch int, @ShowClosed bit
SELECT @CustomerSearch = 2331, @StaffSearch = '', @ShowClosed = CAST(0 AS bit)

SELECT j.JobID, j.JobName, s.JobStatus, jal.[JobAssignmentsFullList]
FROM (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Jobs] WHERE ((NULLIF(@CustomerSearch,'') IS NOT NULL AND CustomerID = @CustomerSearch) OR (NULLIF(@CustomerSearch,'') IS NULL))) j
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM [list].[JobStatuses] WHERE ((@ShowClosed = 0 AND IsStatusOpen = 1) OR (@ShowClosed = 1)) AND IsActive = 1) s ON j.JobStatusID = s.JobStatusID
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[JobAssignments] WHERE ((NULLIF(@StaffSearch,'') IS NOT NULL AND StaffID = @StaffSearch) OR (NULLIF(@StaffSearch,'') IS NULL))) ja ON j.JobID = ja.JobID
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[udv_JobAssignmentsCommaDelimited] jal ON j.JobID = jal.JobID
```

But when I select a customer (specifically the customer whose id is 2331) in debug mode and step through the btnSearch_Click code, cboCustomerID.SelectedValue = "2331", cboStaffID.SelectedValue = "", chkShowClosed.Checked = false (all of which is correct)... but nothing happens when I step past the databind command. The gridview continues to show "No matching jobs on record."

I feel like I'm missing something really obvious, but I can't for the life of me figure out what it is.

UPDATE: Ok. This is interesting. Apparently, the query never gets sent to the SQL Server. I just started up SQL Server in trace mode, reloaded the aspx page, and did a search, and while the queries that are behind the two dropdownlists are there in the log, the query that's behind the gridview is just not there.

UPDATE #2: I've replaced the select parameters with the following:

```
<asp:ControlParameter Name="CustomerSearch" ControlID="cboCustomerID" PropertyName ="SelectedValue" />
<asp:ControlParameter Name="StaffSearch" ControlID="cboStaffID" PropertyName ="SelectedValue" />
<asp:ControlParameter Name="ShowClosed" Type="Boolean" ControlID="chkShowClosed" PropertyName="Checked" />
```

...and removed the extra code in the btnSearch_Click event, so the only line in that code is:

```
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    gvJobs.DataBind();
}
```

...no change. Still nothing happens when I click the search button.

Comment: Quick update: after posting, I discovered that I had the DataKeyNames property of the gridview set to the wrong thing. I've updated it to DataKeyNames="JobID". (will update the post with the new code). It didn't fix this particular problem, though.

Comment: The first thing I would fix is that anti-pattern you have in there that I call "Try/Squelch". The only thing worse than not handling errors is catching them and pretending nothing happened. That query you have there makes me shake my head. Why all the subqueries? I would put a try catch inside your method, with an actual catch. Then step through and see what happens.

Comment: You might want to run a sql trace and see what actual values you are passing to the sql server also.

Comment: Thanks, Sean. Re: the try/catches... in this particular case, I really do want try/squelch. The purpose is to grab the querystrings, if they exist, and if they're called properly (as they always will be when called from the code), then save them and select the appropriate values in the dropdowns. Since the querystrings are optional, I don't want them to error... the result of them being absent or not numeric, is that nothing gets automatically selected in the drop-downs. It's not related to this issue.

Comment: Regarding SQL Trace: Good plan. :) Will see if it's possible to do that (using SQL Server Express 2014)

Comment: I realize it is part of this issue but that is a bad coding practice. Exceptions are expensive from a performance standpoint. Wrap those in an if statement instead. If(Request.QueryString["YourString"]) is not null.

Comment: If you have Profiler you can connect without any issue.

Comment: Update: Ok. This is interesting. Apparently, the query never gets sent to the SQL Server. I just loaded the page and did a search, and while the queries that are behind the two dropdownlists are there in the log, the query that's behind the gridview is just not there.

Comment: Are the `SelectParameters` supposed to be coming from controls on the page?

Comment: Yes, they are. Currently, they are parameters that are filled in during the btnSearch_Click code. I did have them as asp:controlparameters, but that was the first thing I changed to try to fix this problem.

Comment: Another update: I've made a few changes (discovered that my templatefields were wrong, and I also changed the selectparameters back to controlparameters). The question is updated with the new code. Still no change... the btnSearch code still does nothing. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yay! Found the answer:
https://forums.asp.net/t/1243253.aspx?Gridview+Databind+Not+Working

The issue was that the gridviews have a property: CancelSelectOnNullParameter, which is true by default. Since at least one of the drop down lists is almost always null when I do the search, this resulted in nothing happening when I hit the search button. When I added CancelSelectOnNullParameter="false" to the gridview control, it fixed the problem.

(Semi-related note) I also added the following to the ControlParameters: ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true"